# Three "final" versions of Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've played around with IronRuby lately, but I would like to install the reference implementation also. Needless to say, I'm a noob when it comes to Ruby, so I have a very stupid question.

On the [RubyForge download page](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167&release_id=43805), there are three different **final** versions of the Ruby installer (for Windows):

- rubyinstaller-1.8.6-p398.exe
- rubyinstaller-1.8.7-p249.exe
- rubyinstaller-1.9.1-p378.exe

I don't understand how there can be three different final releases. I can understand that there is one 1.8 release, and one 1.9 release, but why can I choose between 1.8.6 and 1.8.7?

What I really would like to know is what version is the "best one" ? If the answer is "1.9.1", why would one choose 1.8.6 or 1.8.7 ?

I'm confused...

Comment: I guess they mean 'stable' in this context

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reasoning behind 3 different versions of the final installers is based on the following criteria:

1.8.6 has been the most widespread version, used in production servers, so the release has been made for compatibility with these cases

1.8.7 is the newer stable standard defined by Ruby-Core, and is the one mostly likely receive attention from Ruby developers for 1.8 branch

1.9.1 is the newer version of Ruby, based on a new Virtual Machine called YARV. This branch (1.9) is the one taking most of the time attention from Ruby-Core developers.

The reason of the packages is that, be able to satisfy 3 different type of users. Ones trying to mimic production environments, ones starting with 1.8 work and ones using newer features.

There is also 1.9.2-preview3, which is one of the version candidates with newer features set to release by August.

Hope that helps.

-

Comment: Note: Luis is the author and maintainer of the RubyInstaller. He knows a thing or two about it.

Answer (score 4):

1.9.1 is the latest release ruby, not the "best".  Typically bleading-edge releases contain incompatibilities with previous releases as well as new functionality.  This makes newer release NOT backward compatible with older releases.  The bottom line is that you want the "older" releases if you plan on running code that was written based on those releases.

Also, one release, usually older, is unofficially recognized as the "stable" and "portable" release. In ruby's case I believe it is the 1.8.7 release.  I good way of checking this is to see what the latest versions of linux or os x have as the pre-installed ruby release.

These are just some of the factors you need to consider when choosing which release to install.  Note that you can have multiple versions of ruby on the same box.  A decent tool for doing this is [rvm](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).

Comment: Why is 1.8.6 also listed as a "final" release on the download page?

Comment: That simply means its the final release of the 1.8.6 branch

Comment: Some people use 1.8.6 For example fedora 12 users all have 1.8.6 because of a desision by the fedora team.

Comment: The three releases are different. 1.9.x is "new generation", 1.8.7 is a middle-road release with some features from 1.9 backported, 1.8.6 is last of the "original" 1.8-train. Slightly simplified...

Comment: Given that the OP is asking questions about the *Windows* installer, the suggestion about RVM isn't exactly helpful. The Windows equivalent is Pik.

Comment: @ennuikiller: No, it doesn't. The "final" refers to the version of the *installer*, it has nothing to do with either Ruby or MRI.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't understand how there can be three different final releases.

There aren't three different final releases, there is only one: "final" in this case means the version of the *installer*, not the *interpreter*. There is only one installer for all three versions of both interpreters.

> I can understand that there is one 1.8 release, and one 1.9 release, but why can I choose between 1.8.6 and 1.8.7?

In Ruby, a change in minor number indicates significant backwards-incompatibility and/or major new language features. The 1.8→1.9 transition has both incompatibilities and new features. While Ruby 1.9 is the current version, there is still a lot of code out there, that hasn't been updated to Ruby 1.9 yet. Also, a lot of operating systems don't yet ship Ruby 1.9 as default, and some don't ship Ruby 1.9 at all.

That's why there is both 1.9 and 1.8.

Why two versions of 1.8? Well, 1.8.7 is this strange netherversion. 1.8.7 got a massive backport of features from 1.9 in order to ease the transition. However, for a long time, 1.8.7 didn't get a lot of acceptance and 1.8.6 is still the recommended version by the Rails team. (This will change with Rails 3 which requires 1.8.7 or the not yet released 1.9.2.)

Ruby 1.8.6 is still the default (and in fact only) version on a lot of the more slowly moving Linux distributions which offer 3-year or 5-years support contracts. Ruby 1.8.6 was also the latest version of the OneClick Installer which was the predecessor of the RubyInstaller. If the RubyInstaller is to be a replacement for the OneClick Installer, it has to offer the same version. And last but not least, there is simply a *ton* of code out there that was tested and validated on 1.8.6.

Also, Ruby 1.8.6 was the version implemented by JRuby 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 and 1.4. Only the recently released JRuby 1.5 upgraded to 1.8.7. JRuby 1.6 will implement both 1.8.7 and 1.9.2. Also, IronRuby 1.0 implements Ruby 1.8.6.

In other words: the RubyInstaller for MRI 1.8.6 is still there for the same reason that Microsoft still supports Windows XP, after having tried to kill it off twice: there's people using it who would get really upset if they didn't.

> What I really would like to know is what version is the "best one" ? If the answer is "1.9.1", why would one choose 1.8.6 or 1.8.7 ?

Personally, I think the "best one" is Ruby 1.9.**2**, which hasn't been released yet.

Here's my personal breakdown:

- if you are just starting with Ruby and play around with it, 1.9.2 is the best version: Ruby 1.9 is the latest version of the language and 1.9.2 is considered to be the feature-complete version of the 1.9 branch; it fixes some oversights and annoyances in 1.9.1 and adds some nice features. Also, most Ruby implementations do not implement 1.9.1, IronRuby will go straight from 1.8.6 to 1.9.2, JRuby will implement both 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 and Rubinius will also go to 1.9.2.
- if you actually want to deploy and/or distribute Ruby applications, 1.9.1 and 1.8.7 are the best versions, simply because 1.9.2 hasn't been officially released yet: use 1.9.1 if you can get away with it (i.e. if the third-party libraries you depend on support it), otherwise 1.8.7.
- if you have a large legacy codebase, use 1.8.6. (Actually, if you have large legacy codebase, update it to 1.9.2 …)

Note that you have to be very careful to distinguish between the version of the *language*, the *implementation*, the version of the implementation and the version of the *installer*.

For example, the first in your list is version 1.8.6 of the *language*, the MRI interpreter, version 1.8.6-p398 of MRI and version "Final" of the installer. The third in you list is version 1.9.1 of the language, the *YARV* compiler/VM (i.e. a *different* implementation from the other two), version 1.9.1-p378 of YARV and also version "Final" of the installer.

Version 1.0 of IronRuby implements version 1.8.6 of Ruby, Version 1.5 of JRuby implements both version 1.8.7 and (a subset of) 1.9.2 of Ruby, selectable by a commandline switch.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. It makes a little more sense now